# how to get the state of a grouped gtk.CheckButton using Action

Tags: rust, gtk4, gtk-rs

I'm trying to get the state of a `gtk.CheckButton` using `Action` since [gtk docs](https://docs.gtk.org/gtk4/class.CheckButton.html) says:

> When the code must keep track of the state of a group of radio buttons, it is recommended to keep track of such state through a stateful GAction with a target for each button. Using the toggled signals to keep track of the group changes and state is discouraged.

```
use gtk::{Application, ApplicationWindow, Button, CheckButton};
use gtk::gio::SimpleAction;
use gtk::Orientation::Vertical;
use gtk::prelude::*;

fn main() {
    let application = Application::builder().application_id("a.b").build();
    application.connect_activate(|application| {
        let main_box = gtk::Box::builder().orientation(Vertical).build();
        let variant_a = "a".to_variant();
        let variant_b = "b".to_variant();
        let window = ApplicationWindow::builder().application(application).child(&main_box).build();
        let action_name = "win.me";
        let action = SimpleAction::new_stateful(action_name, Some(variant_a.type_()), &variant_a);
        window.add_action(&action);
        let button_a = CheckButton::builder().label("a").action_name(action_name)
            .action_target(&variant_a).build();
        main_box.append(&button_a);
        let button_b = CheckButton::builder().label("b").action_name(action_name)
            .action_target(&variant_b).group(&button_a).build();
        main_box.append(&button_b);
        let button = Button::builder().label("click").build();
        action.connect_change_state(|_, state| {
            println!("{:?}", state);
        });
        button.connect_clicked(move |_| {
            println!("{} {:?}", action.name(), action.state());
        });
        main_box.append(&button);
        window.present();
    });
    application.run();
}
```

However the `CheckButton`s are not `sensitive`. Setting `sensitive` to `true` makes them `sensitive` but clicking them won't make them checked.

In another try I used `SimpleActionGroup` and `action-target-value` but with the same results:

```
fn main() {
    let application = Application::builder().application_id("a.b").build();
    application.connect_activate(|application| {
        let main_box = gtk::Box::builder().orientation(Vertical).build();
        let variant_a = "a".to_variant();
        let variant_b = "b".to_variant();
        let window = ApplicationWindow::builder().application(application).child(&main_box).build();
        let action_name = "my.action";
        let action_group = SimpleActionGroup::new();
        window.insert_action_group("my.group", Some(&action_group));
        let action = SimpleAction::new_stateful(action_name, Some(variant_a.type_()), &variant_a);
        action_group.add_action(&action);
        let button_a = CheckButton::builder().label("a").action_name(action_name).build();
        button_a.set_action_target_value(Some(&variant_a));
        main_box.append(&button_a);
        let button_b = CheckButton::builder().label("b").action_name(action_name).group(&button_a).build();
        button_b.set_action_target_value(Some(&variant_b));
        main_box.append(&button_b);
        let button = Button::builder().label("click").build();
        action.connect_activate(|_, state| {
            println!("{:?}", state);
        });
        action.connect_change_state(|_, state| {
            println!("{:?}", state);
        });
        button.connect_clicked(move |_| {
            println!("{} {:?}", action.name(), action.state());
        });
        main_box.append(&button);
        window.present();
    });
    application.run();
}
```

How do I use `Action` to get the state of the grouped `CheckButton`s?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I'm not a RUST programmer, but your code is missing a few things:

1. Besides creating a **SimplesAction**, you also have to create a **SimplesActionGroup** to put the **SimpleAction** inside. You cannot add a **SimpleAction** directly to the window.
2. You should not use `.action_target(&variant...)` , but `.action_target_value(&variant...)`
3. In the **Action's callback function**, you have to manually call `set_state()` to set the "state" of the **Action** to the value received as a parameter in the callback when the "change_state" signal is triggered, which is the **target_value** of the clicked button .

The initial state defined in the **Action** will cause the checkbutton that has this **target_value** to be rendered as active. When you click on another button, the callback will receive the state of the button and `set_state()` will set this new state to the **Action**, which will automatically activate the clicked button, whose `target_value` corresponds to this new state.

Comment: I've updated the question with your suggestions; However the result is the same. I suspect either the variants or the `action-name`

Comment: You are still not setting the action.state in the action callback. I don't know how to do it in Rust but you have to manually define the action.state in the callback, something like this:

` 
action.connect_change_state(|_, state| {
             --> action.set_state(state) <--
             println!("{:?}", state);
         });
`
Otherwise your code looks ok.

Comment: I forgot to mention nothing gets printed; meaning none of the callbacks fire.

Comment: I "translated" your code to python and it works. I think the problem is the Action value and the CheckButton value, types and scope in Rust are more restricted.

For the code to work, the CheckButton value and the Action value must match. This is how the group knows which CheckButton is active: comparing the value of the CheckButton with the current value of the Action, which is why the Action needs to have an initial value.

Answer (score 0):

you could either use an action group:

```
let action_group = SimpleActionGroup::new();
window.insert_action_group("gg", Some(&action_group));
action_group.add_action(&action);
```

and then set the action name: `action_name("gg.aa")`
or directly add the action to the window:

```
    let application = Application::builder().application_id("a.b").build();
    application.connect_activate(|application| {
        let main_box = gtk::Box::builder().orientation(Vertical).build();
        let variant_a = "a".to_variant();
        let window = ApplicationWindow::builder().application(application).child(&main_box).build();
        let action = SimpleAction::new_stateful("aa", Some(variant_a.type_()), &variant_a);
        window.add_action(&action);
        let button_a = CheckButton::builder().label("a").action_name("win.aa")
            .action_target(&variant_a).build();
        main_box.append(&button_a);
        let button_b = CheckButton::builder().label("b").action_name("win.aa").group(&button_a)
            .action_target(&"b".to_variant()).build();
        main_box.append(&button_b);
        action.connect_activate(|action, state| {
            println!("{:?}", state);
            if let Some(state) = state {
                action.set_state(state);
            }
        });
        window.present();
    });
    application.run();
```

for more info see [gtk4-rs book](https://gtk-rs.org/gtk4-rs/stable/latest/book/actions.html).

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the action name on the buttons.

```
use gtk::gio::{SimpleAction, SimpleActionGroup};
use gtk::prelude::*;
use gtk::Orientation::Vertical;
use gtk::{Application, ApplicationWindow, CheckButton};
use gtk4 as gtk;

fn main() {
    let application = Application::builder().application_id("a.b").build();
    application.connect_activate(|application| {
        let main_box = gtk::Box::builder().orientation(Vertical).build();
        let variant_a = "a".to_variant();
        let variant_b = "b".to_variant();
        let window = ApplicationWindow::builder()
            .application(application)
            .child(&main_box)
            .build();
        let action_name = "myaction";
        let action_group = SimpleActionGroup::new();
        window.insert_action_group("mygroup", Some(&action_group));
        let action = SimpleAction::new_stateful(action_name, Some(variant_a.type_()), &variant_a);
        action_group.add_action(&action);
        let button_a = CheckButton::builder()
            .label("a")
            .action_name(action_name)
            .build();
        button_a.set_sensitive(true);
        button_a.set_action_target_value(Some(&variant_a));
        button_a.set_action_name(Some("mygroup.myaction"));
        main_box.append(&button_a);
        let button_b = CheckButton::builder()
            .label("b")
            .action_name(action_name)
            .group(&button_a)
            .build();
        button_b.set_sensitive(true);
        button_b.set_action_target_value(Some(&variant_b));
        button_b.set_action_name(Some("mygroup.myaction"));
        main_box.append(&button_b);
        action.connect_activate(|a, state| {
            println!("Activate: {:?}", state);
            a.set_state(state.expect("New state"));
        });
        window.present();
    });
    application.run();
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).